# How to cause this fixed header div with an absolute menu and a fixed logo take up space?

Tags: css, fixed

There's this fixed `header` element (a block element), with an `absolute` positioned `nav` element with a menu, and another fixed element as the logo:

```
<header>
  <nav id="menu">
    <ul id="menuItems">
       <li class="menu-item" role="menuitem">About</li>
       <li class="menu-item" role="menuitem">Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div id="topLogo">
    <h1>MAIN</h1>
    <h2>SUB</h2>
  </div>
</header>
```

The `<header>` doesn't have dimensions, it doesn't take-up space (check out with an inspector tool). 
I need it to take space (and still be `fixed`).

Look at the JSFiddle to see it with the complete CSS as well: 
https://jsfiddle.net/5amo16q8/4/

Comment: The header does not have dimensions because the element in it are absolute and fixed. So the header dimension will be 0. You have to give the header a height(px) and width(100%);

Comment: The height of the menu is dynamic. I found a solution though, I'll post it...

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `nav` to `float:left` and removing the `position:absolute` seem to create to desired result. 
See: https://jsfiddle.net/5amo16q8/8/